# NSTableView delegate with multiple tables

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

How does one have multiple `NSTableViews` on one `ViewController` with an `NSTableViewDelegate`? How can you differentiate the tables?

For example:
I have `NSTableView *countriesTable` display a list of countries. When a user selects a country, `NSTableView *citiesTable` should load the pertinent cities based on the `selectedRow` of `countriesTable`.

the countries array is an array of country objects, each country object contains properties and another array. So I have to reference the array inside the object selected.

The concept seems easy, but I have had trouble finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag to table view and check on the delegate and datasource methods

like

if([tableview tag] == 1)
{
   `do for table 1`

} else {
   `do for table 2`

}

or

if(tableview == table1)
{
   `do for table 1`

} else {
   `do for table 2`

}